# Is it possible to run an SQL injection attack on a multi-line query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

Suppose I have a multi-line SQL query that accepts input from the user. Is it possible to break using standard SQL injection via comments?

This is for a Microsoft SQL Server query that accepts user input via a Loopback API. Because the same users input is used in multiple spots, I can't seem to write an input that creates a valid SQL query to run an injection attack.

Redacted Code:

```
SELECT Field_Name
FROM Table_Name
WHERE  Field_Name != 'Hardcoded Value' AND (
                Field_1 LIKE '%userinput%' OR
                Field_2 LIKE '%userinput%' OR
                Field_3 LIKE '%userinput%' OR
                Field_4 LIKE '%userinput%'
            )
```

Note that `userinput` is the actual input from the front end, used between two wildcards.

Running this code with a user input of 
`' DROP TABLE USERS; --`
will error out, because of the OR statements.

Is this query breakable via SQL injection?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking here. There isn't any injection or parametrisation in the above query; so it won't suffer from it. If you *are* injecting the values into the above (where `%userinput%` is), then yes, you could. Comments can be added in other ways, for example (`/* This is also a comment */`). There is **never** a good reason to not parametrise your queries and instead inject the values without ensuring that are properly quoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you just need a little more inventiveness. An attacker can easily deduce the shape of your query by just trying more stuff and looking at the errors (or the page output, by crafting targeted `SELECT`s). If we set `userinput` to

```
'); DROP TABLE [BobbyTables]; SELECT 1 FROM Table_Name WHERE ('' = '
```

We end up with a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT Field_Name
FROM Table_Name
WHERE  Field_Name != 'Hardcoded Value' AND (
    Field_1 LIKE '%'); DROP TABLE [BobbyTables]; SELECT 1 FROM Table_Name WHERE ('' = '%' OR
    Field_2 LIKE '%'); DROP TABLE [BobbyTables]; SELECT 1 FROM Table_Name WHERE ('' = '%' OR
    Field_3 LIKE '%'); DROP TABLE [BobbyTables]; SELECT 1 FROM Table_Name WHERE ('' = '%' OR
    Field_4 LIKE '%'); DROP TABLE [BobbyTables]; SELECT 1 FROM Table_Name WHERE ('' = '%'
)
```

Which is syntactically valid and commits quadruple homicide on poor Bobby Tables. Note how we didn't even need comments here; properly matching up delimiters is enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question that is based on some *extremely common misconceptions*.

There are two things, the *possible injection* and the *actual exploit* and it is very important not to confuse them.

- the SQL injection is the possibility to alter the SQL program code based on the user input. Just the possibility.
- the actual exploit is, well... the actual exploit, the payload that performs some action that may change the data in the database or retrieve some data an atacker is not supposed to have access to.

If you cannot come up with a useful exploit, it doesn't mean the injection doesn't exist. It does. And once it does, an exploit will be found, this way or another. As to whether your query is multiline or allowing a comment or disallowing some characters or any other restriction absolutely doesn't matter. the number of exploits is *infinite*, and if a thousand exploits wouldn't work the one thousand first one will do.

So now you can tell that the (in)famous `' DROP TABLE USERS;` exploit in not the synonym for the SQL injection. It's just one of the *infinite number* of possible exploits.

Moreover, although not every API allows you the multiple query execution, so having a delimiter in the query would always produce the syntax error, **it doesn't mean your query is sound and safe**. Even if it's impossible to run a Data Modification Query through SQL injection, it doesn't mean there is no harm. An exploit that gets you data you are not authorized to can be more harmful than a table deletion.

So, what is the takeaway from this rant?

**Yes, this query is breakable via SQL injection,** with fatal consequences.

And from the developer's standpoint, you don't care which particular exploits are possible. You should always fix the injection, the entire possibility, not some particular exploit you are aware of.  For which, you just never let any outside data into your query, as simple as that.

Comment: While your answer contains good stuff (and I've upvoted it), it is not literally the case that *any* query that somehow incorporates a user string will fall to injection. If this were so, *any* use of dynamic SQL would essentially be a guaranteed security hole, which (fortunately for the situations where we need it) is not the case. What is true is that it's hard to say with any degree of certainty that you've set things up in such a way that injection cannot happen (especially since this will vary by database engine), and parameterization is always preferred.

Comment: That's the exact pitiful notion I am taking about.

Comment: As long as functions like `QUOTENAME` are implemented soundly (and assuming that is no more or less safe than assuming the other parts of the engine don't contain security holes, exploitable through a non-dynamic query) a dynamic query text like `'SELECT 1 AS ' + QUOTENAME(@t)` is safe. The output domain can be fully described in this case, as a function of the (admittedly vast) input domain. The same is obviously not the case if arbitrary strings are interpolated, but "altering the code based on user input" covers more than that. (Whether or not it's pitiful is another matter.)